# Angular material radio button group - screen reader not reading properly

Tags: angular-material, accessibility, microsoft-edge, radio-group, narrator

I am using radio button group in my application and it has 3 possible values. Whenever user is selecting a value, screen reader is reading "1 of 1" instead of "1 of 3".

I also checked the behavior on Angular website and it's behaving same.

Sample code : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aalgqoomggld?file=app%2Fradio-overview-example.ts)

Browser: Microsoft Edge
Screen reader: Narrator

Comment: when i view the generated html from your stackblitz example, the two radio buttons have the same `name` attribute ("mat-radio-group-0"), which is the correct way to group the buttons together.  nvda on chrome says "1 of 2" and "2 of 2" so it seems like the correct information is being surfaced (in my setup). have you tried narrator with firefox or chrome?

Comment: @slugolicious - thanks for your response. Is it working for you in Edge + Narrator?

Comment: i don't have w10 so i don't have edge

Comment: @slugolicious - aahhh.. where can I report this bug? Angular or Edge?

Comment: @alok_dida Did you ever get this resolved? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: @MarkHandy - No luck buddy after that and didn't work on it for more than 2 years so not sure Angular team has resolved or not.

Comment: That's what I thought. I'm new at this place and they've been using Material for years. I said I could rebuild these components to make them work, but that's above my pay grade :)

Answer (score 0):

#### .html

```
<label id="example-radio-group-label">Pick your favorite season</label>
<mat-radio-group
  aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label"
  class="example-radio-group"
  [(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason">
  <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">
    {{season}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<div>Your favorite season is: {{favoriteSeason}}</div>
```

#### .ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Radios with ngModel
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'radio-ng-model-example',
  templateUrl: 'radio-ng-model-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['radio-ng-model-example.css'],
})
export class RadioNgModelExample {
  favoriteSeason: string;
  seasons: string[] = ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Looks like, you have understood question in wrong way. I am facing issue with screen reader. When you are selecting Winter, narrator should read 1 of 4 instead of 1 of 1

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to display the checked value, try to refer to the following code and use Model to get the checked value.

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="rdoSeason" aria-label="Select an option">
  <mat-radio-button [value]="1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button [value]="2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button [value]="3">Option 3</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<div>You select Option: {{rdoSeason}}</div>
```

Code in the .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-material-radiobutton',
  templateUrl: './material-radiobutton.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./material-radiobutton.component.css']
})
export class MaterialRadiobuttonComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  rdoSeason:string;
}
```

the result as below:

[image]

More details about using the radio-button label, check [this article](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview).

Comment: Looks like, you have understood question in wrong way. I am facing issue with screen reader. When you are selecting option1 , narrator should read 1 of 3 instead of 1 of 1.